# Should I filter or sanitize potential XSS input values, or just throw an exception

Tags: php, asp.net, security

I've seen many articles and questions on SO regarding filtering and sanitizing web form input values for potential XSS issues.

My question... If we detect XSS issues in the data then shouldn't we be throwing an exception and not allowing the request to progress any further, rather than filtering or sanitizing it?

Comment: That depends. Are you running a forum for programmers in which one may reasonably ask for and receive examples of XSS code? E.g., Stackoverflow couldn't possibly use this strategy.

Comment: That's a good point.  But I imagine in most cases wouldn't want that.

Comment: All the answers for this SO question are to use filtering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php
But if someone is trying to insert XSS like data when they shouldn't be, then shouldn't we throw an exception and stop them getting any further with the request?

Comment: What's XSS-like data? `3<4`?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the kind of data you expects, but in any case it is good to **track in some log that someone have tried a XSS attack** or any other.

One more good practices is to implement an **alert launched when someone tries a XSS attack**. In case you have a lot of traffic you could generate a report daily with all the information about the attacks detected during the day.

After you track this information, if you throw and exception or sanitize the data depends on you, this few questions could help you:

- It is relevant for you the information the user tries to submit?
- Are you interested in let it know you have blocked its XSS attack?
- Are you interested in let it be in web site after detect it as a potential attacker?